# Parse error in echo with php

Tags: php, echo

The error just saying Parse error: parse error in a line, which is the checkbox line in the code below:

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['something']=='1'){
echo '<tr>
<td>
'.$lang['FORM_LABEL_Users_disable'].'
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" '.(if($row['active'] == "0"){echo 'checked = "yes"';}).' name="disable" value="0" ><br>
</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You cannot have an `if` statement inside an `echo` like that.

Comment: I see, then what can I do?

Answer (score 2):

Alternatively, you can insert a ternary operation inside echo. Consider this example:

```
<?php if($_SESSION['something']=='1') {
echo '<tr>
        <td>'.$lang['FORM_LABEL_Users_disable'].'</td>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" '.(($row['active'] == "0") ? 'checked=checked' : '').' name="disable" value="0" ><br>
        </td>
    </tr>';
} ?>
```

> Note: You need to use the proper attribute: **`checked="checked"`** or just **`checked`**

Answer (score 2):

First up all you cannot use an if statement inside an echo like what you did.And also you must escape your string properly.So you can try like the following

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['something']=='1'){
$chkd = '';
if($row["active"] == "0"){
$chkd = 'checked = "yes"';
}
echo '<tr>
<td>
'.$lang["FORM_LABEL_Users_disable"].'
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" '.$chkd.' name="disable" value="0" ><br>
</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You too. You can type that much coding in like 2 minutes, impressive.

Comment: That's why we use `Cntrl + c` , `Cntrl + v`, `Cntrl + A` etc... Haha..;-)

Comment: ha ha by the way what is your daily job? High tech programmer?

Comment: Not hitech.. but a humble programmer... Started like u..

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php if ($_SESSION['something']=='1'){
echo '<tr>
<td>
'.$lang['FORM_LABEL_Users_disable'].'
</td>
<td>
<input type="checkbox" '.($row['active'] == "0"?'checked = "yes"':'').' name="disable" value="0"><br>
</td>
</tr>';
}
?>
```

Comment: @웃웃웃웃웃 yes, he has. *she

Comment: My mistake.. I didn't see the edit..